# I'm being asked to input my password after logging in with biometrics on Fedora 38, using GNOME

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome-keyring, seahorse

This is the message that pops up - **Enter password to unlock your login keyring
The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.**

[image]

From what I've read online, it's a security measure. But if you enter your password on login, this won't pop up since the keyring is unlocked when that password is entered.
But now when I use my fingerprint reader to log into my laptop, it asks for the password after. I should also add that this wasn't the case initially. It only started doing this after a couple of months or so - I'm not sure if an update to Fedora prompted this or not. It's not the end of the world, but annoying. I can just use my password, but then the fingerprint reader is less useful.
I read that you can manage this in Passwords and Keys (formerly Seahorse), but it's not installed natively on Fedora, apparently it is on Ubuntu. If I install Seahorse now, could I use it to manage this? Or is there something in Fedora other than Seahorse, that could do the same thing? I saw a similar post about this here - [Use fingerprint reader for everything but first login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/671075/585410) - My fingerprint reader does let me into my computer, I just still have to use my password to unlock the keyring. It works fine for everything else (making changes, sudo commands in terminal, etc).

Thank you in advance, and I apologize in advance - still learning Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `seahorse` is already installed by searching the gnome app list for "Keys" or something similar. On my system (LMDE 5), `seahorse` is titled "Passwords and Keys".

On the command line you can check if installed by running:

```
dnf info seahorse
```

Once seahorse is installed, you can update the gnome keyring password to empty. Note, this will store your passwords in plain text so it's recommended to do it only if you have full-disk encryption or are reasonably certain your disk will not be misused by someone having physical access to it.

Gnome keyring can currently be unlocked with a password only, so if you're using a passwordless authentication method (fingerprint, Yubikey, etc.) it cannot get the password to auto-unlock the keyring.

Comment: thank you for this info :) i forgot to mention that this only pops up after a restart. if it's just sleeping/locked and i log back in, there's no prompt and the fingerprint unlocks it just fine. guessing after a restart or something, i just have to remember to use the password for a smoother action. but i'm definitely going to look at seahorse and install it. i did look for it and passwords and keys in the app list, but it didn't show up. 
thanks again for the info, much appreciated!

Comment: @sbarnard86 The gnome keyring stays unlocked even if the lockscreen is activated. They're not related. If you don't mind entering the password once when booting the system and thereby unlocking the gnome keyring as well, edit the display/login manager gdm (on gnome) PAM file in `/etc/pam.d` directory. For details on PAM see `man 7 pam`, for PAM config `man 5 pam.conf`. I have to warn you though, a PAM misconfiguration can lock you out, so test it while logged into a root shell, modifying the PAM file for sudo and running sudo <cmd> in a new terminal.